# How do you plot an ROC curve for a 1 nearest neighbor classifier

Tags: knn, roc

I want to evaluate my KNN where K = 1 classifier against Support Vector Machine Classifiers etc but I'm not sure if the way I am computing the ROC plot is correct. The classifier is constructed for a two class problem (positive and negative class).

If I understand correctly, to compute the ROC for a KNN for K=20, to get the first point on the plot we would get the true positive and false positive values for the tests samples where 1 or more of the 20 nearest neighbors are of the positive class. To get the second point we evaluate the true positive and false positive values for the test samples where 2 or more of the 20 nearest neighbors are of the positive class. This is repeated until the threshold reaches 20 out of 20 nearest neighbors.

For the case where K=1, does the ROC curve simply only have 1 point on the plot? Is there a better way to compute the ROC for the 1NN case? How can we fairly evaluate the performance for the 1NN classifier to a SVM classifier? Can we only compare the performance of the classifiers only at the single false positive value of the 1NN classifier?